# how to retreive a list of data from firebase and store it into ArrayList<>

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase database and I want to retreive a list of data from there and store into ArrayList.

Product model is fine, working.

```
class Product(var pName: String?, var pUnit: Int, var pPrice: Double, var pAmount: Double)
```

But somehow I cannot get the list of "items" from database.
What I want is to get `pname`, `punit`, `pprice`, and `pamount` and store it in `ArrayList<Product>`

[image]

my reference to database is this;

```
 ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Sales")

    ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

        }

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {

            var sira: Int = 0

            ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

                }

                override fun onDataChange(p1: DataSnapshot) {

                    println("onDataChange")
                    if (p0.exists()) {

                        list.clear()


                        for (h in p0.children) {


                            val dateR = h.child("date").value.toString()
                            val discountR = h.child("discount").value.toString()
                            val dueR = h.child("due").value.toString()
                            val nameR = h.child("name").value.toString()
                            val totalR = h.child("total").value.toString()
                            val subtotalR = h.child("subTotal").value.toString()
                            val timeR = h.child("time").value.toString()

                            val name = h.child("pname").value.toString()
                            val unit = h.child("punit").value.toString()
                            val price = h.child("pprice").value.toString()
                            val amount = h.child("pamount").value.toString()


                            productList.add(Product(name, unit.toInt(), price.toDouble(), amount.toDouble()))
```

here is the `json` file

```
{
"-Lw37--uyfuBA0AfTalp" : {
"date" : "14/12/2019",
"discount" : 0.24,
"due" : 0,
"items" : [ {
  "pamount" : 2.4,
  "pname" : "Granola",
  "pprice" : 2.4,
  "punit" : 1
  } ],
  "paym" : [ {
  "paymentAmnt" : 0.02,
  "paymentDesc" : "Cash Payment :"
   }, {
  "paymentAmnt" : 2.14,
  "paymentDesc" : "Card Payment :"
   } ],
  "subTotal" : 2.4,
  "time" : "11:16:42",
  "total" : 2.16
  },
  "-Lw5Qx8sVdw3ZCMiXAL-" : {
  "date" : "14/12/2019",
  "discount" : 1,
  "due" : 0,
  "items" : [ {
  "pamount" : 4.8,
  "pname" : "Granola",
  "pprice" : 2.4,
  "punit" : 2
  }, {
  "pamount" : 2.6,
  "pname" : "Brownie",
  "pprice" : 2.6,
  "punit" : 1
}, {
  "pamount" : 2.6,
  "pname" : "Brownie",
  "pprice" : 2.6,
  "punit" : 1
   } ],
  "name" : "James Brown",
  "paym" : [ {
  "paymentAmnt" : 3,
  "paymentDesc" : "Cash Payment :"
  }, {
  "paymentAmnt" : 5,
  "paymentDesc" : "Staff Markout :"
   }, {
  "paymentAmnt" : 1,
  "paymentDesc" : "Card Payment :"
   } ],
  "subTotal" : 10,
  "time" : "22:03:07",
  "total" : 9
  },
  "-Lw5T4TfYUTXsWKAndBx" : {
  "date" : "14/12/2019",
  "discount" : 0.24,
  "due" : -0.84,
  "items" : [ {
  "pamount" : 2.4,
  "pname" : "Granola",
  "pprice" : 2.4,
  "punit" : 1
  } ],
  "name" : "James Brown",
  "paym" : [ {
  "paymentAmnt" : 3,
  "paymentDesc" : "Cash Payment :"
  } ],
  "subTotal" : 2.4,
  "time" : "22:12:26",
  "total" : 2.16
  },
  "-Lw5UWguHS18IwWE6elT" : {
  "date" : "14/12/2019",
  "discount" : 0.26,
  "due" : -1.66,
  "items" : [ {
  "pamount" : 2.6,
  "pname" : "Brownie",
  "pprice" : 2.6,
  "punit" : 1
  } ],
  "name" : "James Brown",
  "paym" : [ {
  "paymentAmnt" : 4,
  "paymentDesc" : "Cash Payment :"
  } ],
  "subTotal" : 2.6,
  "time" : "22:18:43",
  "total" : 2.34
  },
  "-Lw5ypp5xJLJO53bjejk" : {
  "date" : "15/12/2019",
  "discount" : 0,
  "due" : -1.6,
  "items" : [ {
  "pamount" : 2.4,
  "pname" : "Granola",
  "pprice" : 2.4,
  "punit" : 1
  } ],
  "name" : "James Brown",
  "paym" : [ {
  "paymentAmnt" : 4,
  "paymentDesc" : "Cash Payment :"
   } ],
   "subTotal" : 2.4,
   "time" : "00:35:32",
   "total" : 2.4
   },
   "-LwANPC0UYCmTnqm7DRV" : {
   "date" : "15/12/2019",
   "discount" : 1,
   "due" : 0,
   "items" : [ {
  "pamount" : 2.4,
  "pname" : "Granola",
  "pprice" : 2.4,
  "punit" : 1
   }, {
  "pamount" : 2.6,
  "pname" : "Brownie",
  "pprice" : 2.6,
  "punit" : 1
   }, {
  "pamount" : 2.4,
  "pname" : "Granola",
  "pprice" : 2.4,
  "punit" : 1
   }, {
  "pamount" : 2.6,
  "pname" : "Brownie",
  "pprice" : 2.6,
  "punit" : 1
   } ],
   "name" : "James Brown",
   "paym" : [ {
  "paymentAmnt" : 5,
  "paymentDesc" : "Cash Payment :"
   }, {
  "paymentAmnt" : 4,
  "paymentDesc" : "Card Payment :"
   } ],
   "subTotal" : 10,
   "time" : "21:05:43",
   "total" : 9
    }
    }
```

But, please help me what I am doing wrong here. any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: can you export file data firebase, I want to import firebase and testing

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: hi, thanks for your interest. I have added json file in the question.

Comment: I answered you can check

Comment: I noticed this way only getting all product entries from firebase. is it possible to make it only show based on the specific key value. (for example, i want it to show only the product list under ` "-Lw5Qx8sVdw3ZCMiXAL-"` key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try: Use GenericTypeIndicator to get List data.

You can refer my github:https://github.com/vancuong0429/stack_59350042

```
private lateinit var database: DatabaseReference
private var productList: ArrayList<Product> = arrayListOf()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Sales")
    database.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

        }

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            productList.clear()
            for (snapshot in p0.children) {
                if (snapshot.hasChild("items")) {
                    val generic: GenericTypeIndicator<List<Product>> =
                        object : GenericTypeIndicator<List<Product>>() {}
                    val items = snapshot.child("items").getValue(generic)
                    items?.let { productList.addAll(it) }
                }
            }
        }

    })
}
class Product {
    var pName: String? = null
    var pUnit: Int? = null
    var pPrice: Double? = null
    var pAmount: Double? = null
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but it is giving an error `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Generic wildcard types are not supported`

Comment: You can fix List to ArrayList: val generic: GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<Product>>
                            = object : GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<Product>>() {}

Comment: Thanks, @Cường Nguyễn that worked with ArrayList. Great solution.